# Can we memset same size with the size we can malloc?

Tags: linux, memory-management, ubuntu, malloc, memset

ubuntu 10.04 LTS(2.6.32-38-generic) i686 - intel i7 - 16GB

I got a `map failed` error to `memset` certain amount of memory. Do you have any idea? Additional information is I could `malloc` the same size. Here's my code.

```
    //Here I could malloc successfully
    pdev->frame_buffer = (uint16_t *)malloc(3840000);
    //Then, I got map_failed error here and message from compiler is "Invalid argument"
    if((pdev->frame_buffer = (uint16_t *)mmap(0, 3840000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb, 0)) == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("Error: cannot mmap frame buffer");
        exit(1);
    }
```

If I `mmap` smaller than the size I tried above like `mmap(0, 100,...)`, then it returns right address. I'm not sure if this issue is because of the size.

Do you have any guess why it happend?

Answer (score 0):

Your memset actually has an off-by-one error. You've malloc'd 3,840,000 bytes, but your meset range specifies a total of 3,840,001 bytes to set. The args should be

```
if((pdev->frame_buffer = (uint16_t *)mmap(0, 3839999, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb, 0)) == MAP_FAILED){
                                             ^^^^^^^---note the change.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example does not contain `memset` at all, only `malloc` and `mmap`?

My guess as to *why* `mmap` fails is that the file descriptor refers to the framebuffer (the context suggests so, both from the variable name `frame_buffer` and the file descriptor `fb`), and you have a combination of "allocated larger than framebuffer", "allocated with a permission/flag combination that the driver does not like" and "some other obscure reason".

Mapping the framebuffer or any other device memory is *not* as trivial as mapping normal memory or a file (well, it kind of is, but then again, not), there can be many more obvious and less obvious reasons why this might fail.

The first obvious thing to look for would be if your current screen resolution times bytes-per-pixel adds up to 3840000 at all. If it doesn't, you're out of bounds.